# Angular 2 http does not catch connection refused error

Tags: angular, typescript, http, try-catch

I want to catch all http errors to inform the user of an occurred problem.

So, I created a method that does a http get with a catch.

```
get(path: string): Promise<any> {
  let headers = new Headers();
  return this.http.get(path, { headers: headers })
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => { ... })
    .catch((response: Response) => { this.errorHandler(response); });
}
```

When the path parameter is '/fault-url' the catch is handled as expected.

But when the path is 'http://localhost:5000/fault-url' the error is not catched by the catch method.
I've added logging to all different places, but it seams the get method just aborts.
The console log shows following errors

> OPTIONS http://localhost:5000/fault-url net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
>
> EXCEPTION: Response with status: 0 for URL: null
>
> Uncaught Response {_body: ProgressEvent, status: 0, ok: false, statusText: "", headers: Headers…}

Does http realy abort or am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After upgrading to Angular 2.3.0 the problem is solved.

Comment: Can you give me details about how to handle this error ?

Comment: Sorry @duardbr, I don't understand your question.
If an error occurs while doing a get request, the catch returns the reason of the failure. This reason can for example be used to inform the user.